# How can I set column values to GridView Columns?

Tags: asp.net, csv, gridview

I have csv file like this:

[image]

I need to show this csv file with gridview. But I must change format like this:

[image]

I must select distinct just date and mount columns and use date values on gridview columns.

How can I use values of csv file for Gridview columns?

Comment: How do you read the CSV file? Is that part of your question or do you have already something like `List<ClassName>` or `DataTable` or `List<string[]>`?

Comment: I use `Sqldatasource` with `Odbc` without code.

Comment: So you want some kind of pivot, rows to columns? Are the days known?

Comment: Yes. But day values will be last 7 days in csv files(for example: 12 May... 18 May). And it's not static.

Comment: So you don't need to get the days from the data but you could use them statically? Do you need the values for every day or only for days where you have values?

Comment: So how can I set datetime.now and yesterday and ... to gridview columns?

Comment: I need the values only for days where I have values.

Comment: Please give next time proper informations in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that reading the CSV file is not an issue and you have already something like a `List<ClassName>`, `DataTable` or `List<string[]>`. I'm presuming that it's a `List<String[]>` where the first "column" is `Date`, the second `Mount` and the last `%` in my following approach.

You need  real `DateTime`s and `int`s to be able to sum percents by date:

```
var formatProvider = new CultureInfo("de-DE");  // seems to be the correct format

var mountGroups = listOfStringArray
   .Select(arr => new
   {
       Date = DateTime.Parse(arr[0].Trim(), formatProvider).Date,
       Mount = arr[1].Trim(),
       Percent = int.Parse(arr[2].Trim())
   })
   .GroupBy(x => x.Mount);
```

Now you have grouped by `Mount`, you just need to sum the percents for every day. You can use a `DataTable` as datasource for the `GridView`. Here's code that creates the table with the dynamic columns for every day:

```
var dataSource = new DataTable();
dataSource.Columns.Add("Mount");
var lastWeekColumns = Enumerable.Range(0, 7)
    .Select(d => new DataColumn(DateTime.Today.AddDays(-6 + d).ToShortDateString(), typeof(int)))
    .ToArray();
dataSource.Columns.AddRange(lastWeekColumns);
```

Following loop executes the LINQ query and fills the table:

```
foreach(var grp in mountGroups)
{
    DataRow row = dataSource.Rows.Add();
    row.SetField("Mount", grp.Key); // because: GroupBy(x => x.Mount);
    foreach(DataColumn dayCol in lastWeekColumns)
    {
        DateTime day = DateTime.Parse(dayCol.ColumnName, formatProvider);
        int sumPercent = grp.Where(x => x.Date == day)
            .Select(x => x.Percent)
            .DefaultIfEmpty(0)  // fallback value for missing days
            .Sum();
        row.SetField(dayCol, sumPercent);
    }
}
```

Now you just need to use it as datasource (`AuthoGenerateColumns` set to `true`)

```
grid.DataSource = dataSource;
grid.DataBind();
```